# Remove all characters from string, except specific multibyte range

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl, unicode

How would one use `sed` or another tool to remove all characters **except** a specific multibyte range?

For instance, the range `\xd8\xa0 - \xd9\x8a` covers Arabic characters encoded in UTF-8. This was my naive hopeful attempt at using sed:

```
$ echo "Peace be upon you. السلام عليكم. שלום עליכם. Paz sobre vosotros." | sed -n -e 's|[^\xd8\xa0-\xd9\x8a]||p'
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: Invalid range end
```

Had `sed` understood multibyte characters, that should have left us with the string:

```
السلام عليكم
```

I have considered using `iconv` to convert to some Arabic-specific encoding, use `sed`, then convert back. However the work that I'm doing is non-trival, such as I might want to preserve both Arabic and Hebrew, so I'd like to keep everything in UTF-8 for the entire time if possible.

**If `sed` cannot work with multibyte characters, what should I use? I've searched for both `sed` and `perl` solutions with no luck.**

Note that I've tried to add a `UTF-8` tag to the question, but unix.SE changes that to a `Unicode` tag. There is no Unicode here, these are encoded strings stored on disk. I think that there should be a separate `UTF-8` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Unicode properties](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#Unicode-Properties) in Perl:

```
echo "Peace be upon you. السلام عليكم. שלום עליכם. Paz sobre vosotros." \
| perl -CIO -pe 's/\P{Arabic}//g'
```

- `-CIO` tells Perl that input and output are UTF-8 encoded.
- `\P{...}` is a negative property match, `\p{...}` would be a positive one.

Comment: Thank you! Why is perl so hard to search for?!? Even with your answer right in front of me I cannot fine the `C` flag documented or how I would have discovered `\p{Foo}`.

Comment: [-C](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-C-%5Bnumber/list%5D)

Comment: @dotancohen See the man pages for `perlre`, [perlunicode](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode), `perluniintro`, `perlunitut`, `utf8`, and `perluniprops`. The man pages for `Encode::Unicode` and `Encode` may also be useful.  Also, google "perl unicode".    (I've linked to `perlunicode`, the others are linked at the bottom of that page).  There's a LOT of info and documentation, and some of it will be obsolete (so check the dates on any results) - unicode support in perl is a complex topic, and has evolved over the last few decades.

Comment: @cas Thank you! `man perl` is near useless, but I just installed perldoc to get access to the actual docs.

Comment: `man perl` isn't useless, it's an index page guiding you to specific topics of interest, such as overviews, tutorials, reference manuals, faqs, and more. perl is too big to document in one man page.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Sample Input (OP's text saved as a one-line file):

```
~$ cat peace.txt
Peace be upon you. السلام عليكم. שלום עליכם. Paz sobre vosotros.
```

Extract Arabic script:

```
~$ raku -ne 'put m:g/ <:Script<Arabic>>+ /;' peace.txt
السلام عليكم
```

Extract Hebrew script:

```
~$ raku -ne 'put m:g/ <:Script<Hebrew>>+ /;' peace.txt
שלום עליכם
```

Extract Latin script:

```
~$ raku -ne 'put m:g/ <:Script<Latin>>+ /;' peace.txt
Peace be upon you Paz sobre vosotros
```

Raku provides high-level support for Unicode, and it's Regex engine has grown to be a capable "grammar parser". See the links below. Note, the code above will return blank lines if no match. If you only want matching elements/lines you can simply add a conditional call to the `$/` (or `$<>`) match variable:

```
~$ cat peace2.txt #(remove terminal period from each phrase)
Peace be upon you
السلام عليكم
שלום עליכם
Paz sobre vosotros

~$ raku -ne 'put m:g/ <:Script<Latin>>+ /;' peace2.txt
Peace be upon you


Paz sobre vosotros

~$ raku -ne 'put $/ if m:g/ <:Script<Latin>>+ /;' peace2.txt
Peace be upon you
Paz sobre vosotros
```

Finally, you can search for the negation of a Unicode property by interposing a `!` character. You can also add (or even subtract) from the desired character class(es) with `+` and/or `-`.  *[Note additional regex atom `:Z` (whitespace) below. In the interest of completeness the code below shows both `+` and `!` parameters--although a `-` might work in practice]:*

```
~$ raku -ne 'put $/ if m:g/ <+:!Script<Latin> + :!Z >+ /' peace2.txt
السلام عليكم
שלום עליכם
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode
https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode#index-entry-UTF-8_Clean-8
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66540269/7270649

Comment: Terrific answer, thank you. This concisely covers much material that I will likely need sometime.

Comment: Thank you, @dotancohen! I also wanted to mention in addition to the Unicode  `<:Script< … >>` property, Raku also lets you define regex characters via the Unicode block property, e.g. `<:Block("Basic Latin")>` or `<:Block(q{Basic Latin})>`, albeit with a slightly-different calling syntax (most likely to escape the enclosed text properly).

Comment: I foresee much sed and awk being replaced with Raku in my future. I'd until now avoided `perl` unless absolutely necessary due to the "12 ways to do anything" nature of the language. But I really like the way `perl` replaces both `sed` and `awk`, I should invest in learning that List Comprehension-type syntax.